# Unable to instantiate an error in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hbase, nosql

Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

I just installed hive on hbase and hadoop but when i try show databases and create table commands in the hive> prompt giving me the error as below: `create database saty;
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask`

please help me to create hive-site.xml and env-hive.sh config files .

Answer (score 0):

Are you created meta data in mysql and did you change hive-site.xml file.